# create node with multiple attribute

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I want to create a node script and set it with multiple attributes

This is want I am trying to do:

```
$script_insta_node = $dom->createElement('script');
$script_insta_node->setAttribute('async defer src', $instagram_js_path);
```

The problem is that I can only define one attribute.

Comment: What prevents you from defining a custom function that takes in a variable and performs the calls you need on it?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is extend [`DOMElement`](https://secure.php.net/manual/class.domelement.php) (the class that defines the attribute mutator methods) and then register them with [`DOMDocument`](https://secure.php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php).

If you want to get a little more fancy, you could extend `DOMDocument` as well, to incorporate this behavior by default, for instance in your own namespace `Dom`;

**Dom\Element**:

```php
namespace Dom;

class Element
  extends \DOMElement
{
  // I think something like this would make
  // a little more sense than your original example
  // that would probably set all attributes to the same value
  public function setAttributes( array $attributes ) {
    foreach( $attributes as $name => $value ) {
      $this->setAttribute( $name, $value );
    }
  }
}
```

**Dom\Document**:

```php
namespace Dom;

class Document
  extends \DOMDocument
{
  public function __construct( $version = '1.0', $encoding = null ) {
    parent::__construct( $version, $encoding );

    // we register our custom DOMElement class
    // you can do this for all DOM classes
    // that are derivatives of DOMNode
    $this->registerNodeClass( 'DOMElement', 'Dom\Element' );
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```php
$doc = new Dom\Document;
$scriptElement = $doc->createElement( 'script' );
$scriptElement->setAttributes( array(
  'defer' => '',
  'async' => '',
  'src'   => $instagram_js_path
) );
```